# Cannot POST in nodejs and mongodb on openshift

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, openshift

This is my ajax post request. I am using nodejs and mongodb.When I post a request I get an error stating CANNOT POST.currlocation in the POST request is the json object. I have also tried to remove the content-type from POST request and tried to send the data as JSON.stringify(currlocation),it still doesnt work

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://myurl.rhcloud.com",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: currLocation,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function( response ){
            console.log(response);                  

        },
        error: function( error ){
            console.log( "ERROR:", error );
        }
        });
```

I am using nodejs and mongodb. My configuration in server.js file is

```
self.app.configure(function () {
            self.app.use(express.bodyParser());
            self.app.use(express.favicon());
            self.app.use(express.json());
            self.app.use(express.urlencoded());
            self.app.use(express.methodOverride());
            self.app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true      }));


      });
```

My post request in server.js file is

```
self.app.post('/', self.routes['post'] );
  self.routes['post'] = function(req, res){
        console.log("inside post");
               var mongojs = require('mongojs');
                var dbName = "/favloc";
                var connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + dbName;
                console.log("conncetion string"+connection_string);
                var db = mongojs(connection_string, ['location']);
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
                 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');                
                 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);



               db.collection('location').insert({'city' : "sf",'id':'2'}, function(result){
                console.log("success");
                  res.send(req.body.self);
               //  res.end('success');
            });
       };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CANNOT POST in jquery ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206018/cannot-post-in-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax()` doesn't make real `POST` requests.

I think it actually sends a `GET` request with the `Access-Control-Request-Method` Header set to `POST`.

You can add support for this behavior by adapting your server-side code to match.