# CANNOT POST in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

This is my ajax post request. When I post a request to nodejs, I get an error stating CANNOT POST.My server side script is in nodejs express.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://abc.rhcloud.com",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(currlocation),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function( response ){
        console.log(response);                  

    },
    error: function( error ){
        console.log( "ERROR:", error );
    }
    });
```

UPDATED:
This is my server.js file

My post request in server.js file is

```
self.app.post('/', self.routes['post'] );
  self.routes['post'] = function(req, res){
        console.log("inside post");
               var mongojs = require('mongojs');
                var dbName = "/favloc";
                var connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + dbName;
                console.log("conncetion string"+connection_string);
                var db = mongojs(connection_string, ['location']);
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
                 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');                
                 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);



               db.collection('location').insert({'city' : "sf",'id':'2'}, function(result){
                console.log("success");
                  res.send(req.body.self);
               //  res.end('success');
            });
       };
```

Comment: shouldn't the url be to a json file, not just a subdomain?

Comment: How do i add a json file to the url

Comment: Your jquery looks fine - show your node.js code that listens for post reuests at abc.rhcloud.com

Comment: I have edited to add server.js code in my question

Comment: From which domain requested ajax?

Comment: i am sending request from http://abc.rhcloud.com to get request from http://abc.rhcloud.com. Its not crossdomain

Comment: @misthacoder did you ever fix this?  I'm having the same error and can't figure it out.