# cannot POST .php email

Tags: php, post, openshift

Whenever I try to send myself an email using the following code, I keep getting this error:

> Cannot POST /assets/php/sendemail.php

I am not familiar enough with php to debug this, and everything I have tried so far doesn't seem to be working out.

The php file is in the correct directory, so I do know at least that much is correct.

Any help in debugging would be great, thank you!

---

#### My HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="contact-form">
    <strong>Send me a message</strong>
    <form name="contact-form" method="post" action="assets/php/sendemail.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputName1">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="InputName1" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputEmail1">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail1" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputSubject">Subject</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="InputSubject">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputTextarea">Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="InputTextarea" rows="5" required=""></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

#### My PHP code:

```
$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject']));
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'myemail@email.com'; //replace with your email

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $body, 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message);
```

Folder Structure:

Use server on OpenShift

[image]

Comment: I think `assets/php/sendemail.php` this is the problem, your form not able to send data on this php page. try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1)` just after `<?php` in your php page and check once. Also if you are trying it on local thrn it will not send a mail. You have to do some more stuff.

Comment: @A-2-A I'm running on a server so that's not the problem, I'll throw the error checking in and let you know what happens

Comment: @A-2-A I'm not getting anything besides the can't POST error still

Comment: can you tell me the folder structure between the html and the php? For what you have written you have a subfolder assets/php that contais sendmail.php starting from where the html is. This error tells you that the php sendmail.php cannot be located

Comment: folder structure is now added.  the page which I am trying to navigate from is on the same level as the assets folder @LelioFaieta

Comment: Then just put sendemail.php as folder action

Comment: What web server you use? I think there is problem not with php, but with web server. It like as your web server not allow POST method.

Comment: @newman I am using openshift to host the site for now, using a `.rhcloud.com` extension

Comment: Similar problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205500/cannot-post-in-nodejs-and-mongodb-on-openshift and

Answer (score 1):

First you can debug by keeping php code on page. I mean in `<?php` tag use

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); }
```

you can print array like above so you come to know is it coming into that scope or something else.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this

Answer (score 0):

For debug add this 2 lines after `<?php`, just like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then display the content of the variable you are debugging.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

I suggest you to use a extension or library, i've used Xdebug a couple of times and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is not problem with PHP. Request just stop on web server and don't passed to PHP backend.

I think it need configure in OpenShift. Now server allow only GET request. I'm don't know how configure it. Try with options in control panel or in config files. Or ask hosting support team.